# Определение текущей страницы в прокручиваемом меню

Tags: php, request

Всем доброго дня! Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать правильнее:
 Есть меню (вертикальное, с ползунком), в котором около 100 пунктов. Необходимо с помощью определения урл и сравнения со ссылкой в пункте отобразить текущий пункт. Решение конечно простое - можно просто сравнить REQUEST_URI со ссылками. Но проблема в том, что все меню это выборка из базы с помощью while. Как правильно встроить логику if в такую конструкцию?

```
$current = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
while ($inf = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if("spravochnik-".$sf.'/'.$inf['url'] == $current) $clstatus='class="current"';
    echo '<a href="spravochnik-'.$sf.'/'.$inf['url'].'"><li '.$clstatus.'>'.$inf['code'].'</li></a>';
}
```

Если делать так, то я получаю правильное определение, но на все пункты.

Comment: И вопрос не особо понятен и ответ ещё больше запутывает. Логика if УЖЕ была, УЖЕ проверяла текущий пункт. Тогда возникает вопрос "для чего встраивать логику IF в эту конструкцию? То есть что за задача? Лично я в недоумении. Ответ без кода в этой ситуации лишь увеличивает недоумение.

Comment: В примере, логика не дает нужного результата, так как нет условия else

Comment: Знаете, ни в задании нет формулировки какой нужен результат, ни в ответе не пояснено. Это вряд ли стоит назвать хорошим вопросом, который поможет другим людям даже если они наткнутся на него в поиске. Пока что он понятен и полезен только одному человеку. Рекомендую в будущем как-то более чётко формулировать задачу и подробнее описывать ответы.